# concatenate __MODULE__ with string

Tags: elixir

how can i concatenate `__MODULE__` with a string ?

temp=`__MODULE__` <> "/blabla" does not work

if `__MODULE__` is Elixir.Tasks.Process.Lixo than i need the temp var to be

"Elixir.Tasks.Process.Lixo/blabla"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__MODULE__` just references your current module. It returns an atom, which can't be concatenated with a string. In order to do so you need to convert it to a string with [to_string/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/String.Chars.html#to_string/1):

```
to_string(Elixir.Tasks.Process.Lixo) <> "/foo"
# => "Elixir.Tasks.Process.Lixo/foo"
```

You can also use string interpolation which implicitly called `to_string/1`:

```
"#{Elixir.Tasks.Process.Lixo}/foo"
# => "Elixir.Tasks.Process.Lixo/foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Module.concat`. For instance:

```
Module.concat(Foo.Bar, Baz)    # => Foo.Bar.Baz
Module.concat([Foo, Bar, Baz]) # => Foo.Bar.Baz
Module.concat(__MODULE__, Baz) # => Foo.Bar.Baz if current module is Foo.Bar
```

Doing it this way will keep it an atom as you expect and avoid conversion to a binary and back, etc.